# Rewrite everything after url pattern + htaccess

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm currently loading some jobs from a service and I've build the url this way:

```
mysite.com/job-detail/job-title
```

The `job-detail` in the url will always stay the same while the `job-title` will depend on what's coming out of the API.

Since I'm using Wordpress I would like to make sure that all the `/job-detail/xxx` pages are using the same template so I can display my data as I wish.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself:

```
add_action('init', 'fake_page_rewrite');

function fake_page_rewrite(){

global $wp_rewrite;

//set up our query variable %fake_page% which equates to index.php?fake_page=
add_rewrite_tag( '%fake_page%', '([^&]+)');

//add rewrite rule that matches /blog
add_rewrite_rule('^job-detail/?','index.php?fake_page=themes/subjects','top');

//add endpoint, in this case 'blog' to satisfy our rewrite rule /blog, /blog/page/ etc..
add_rewrite_endpoint( 'job-detail', EP_PERMALINK | EP_PAGES );

//flush rules to get this to work properly
$wp_rewrite->flush_rules();

}



add_action('template_redirect', 'fake_page_redirect');

function fake_page_redirect(){

    global $wp;

    //retrieve the query vars and store as variable $template
    $template = $wp->query_vars;

    //pass the $template variable into the conditional statement and
    //check if the key 'fake_page' is one of the query_vars held in the $template array
    //and that 'blog' is equal to the value of the key which is set
    if ( array_key_exists( 'fake_page', $template ) && 'themes/subjects' == $template['fake_page'] ) {

        //if the key 'fake_page' exists and 'blog' matches the value of that key
        //then return the template specified below to handle presentation
        include( get_stylesheet_directory().'/template-job.php' );

        exit;

    }
}
```